# ListView does not update anymore after deletion of the first ListView child

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I'm having a problem with my ListView I developed. If I remove the first child of my ListView. All other childs don't update anymore.

If I delete the last child, the childs in the middle it keeps on updating. But as soon as I delete the first child of the ListView, every child stops updating.

The ListView is still clickable.

**ListView creation:**

```
listView.setAdapter(mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Progress>(getActivity(), R.layout.progressbar_list, R.id.textView, a){

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            upadteRow(getItem(position), v, position, 500);
            return v;
        }
    });
```

**add elements:**

```
public static void addItems(View v, Context ctx){

    mAdapter.add(new Progress());
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    ctx.stopService(intent);

    intent = new Intent(ctx, DownloadingService.class);
    intent.putExtra("files", mAdapter.getCount());
    ctx.startService(intent);
}
```

**remove Items:**

```
act.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            tasks.remove(clicked_position);

                            a.remove(a.get(clicked_position));

                            //mAdapter.remove(a.get(clicked_position));
                            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                            clicked_position = 500;

                            Log.e("REMOVED", "" +  a.size() + " listview " + listView.getCount() + " mlistview " + mListView.getCount());

                        }
                    });
```

Maybe you guys, can give me some hints what the cause of this problem coud be.

Comment: View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            upadteRow(getItem(position), v, position, 500);notifyDataSetChanged();
            return v;

Comment: try this it may help u

Comment: @AbhishekChaubey with notifyDataSetChanged(); added, the childs don't even start to update at the launch.

Comment: What is the `a` in the `Runnable` referencing?

Comment: @JaySoyer the `a` does refer to an ArrayList.
`private static ArrayList<Progress> a = new ArrayList<Progress>();`